# Moving a field of an object in vector index

Tags: rust, move, ownership

My question aims at understanding a deeper variant of the "cannot move out of index" error, specifically when I want to move a *field* of a struct that resides in a vector. Below is a classical example of a vector of objects and an attempt to move a field out of it.

```rust
struct Foo {
    str_val: String,
    int_val: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut foos = Vec::new();
    foos.push(Foo {
        str_val: "ten".to_string(),
        int_val: 10,
    });
    foos.push(Foo {
        str_val: "twenty".to_string(),
        int_val: 20,
    });

    // Here understandable error.
    let moved = foos[0];

    // Why also an error? "cannot move out of index of `Vec<Foo>`" 
    let moved_field = foos[0].str_val;
}
```

My question:

- while I *do* understand why one cannot move the whole object occupying the element of the index (i.e. because the contiguous index is its owner), but
- what I don't understand is why one cannot move a field of such an object.

  - The logical counter-reasoning I have is that it *is* allowed to move a field out of a standalone object, and rust appears advanced enough to track the ownership of fields separately:

```rust
let mut standalone = Foo {
    str_val: "thirty".to_string(),
    int_val: 30,
};
let moved_thirty = standalone.str_val;

// Rust seems to be completely ok with tracking fields separately.
let int_moved = standalone.i32;
//  "use of moved value: `standalone.str_val`" 
let error = standalone.str_val;
```

Comment: When you make a partial move out of a variable the parent variable cannot be used as a whole anymore, since you have stored the object in a vector this is forbidden, for instance the vector may need to move to reallocate more space.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of "object invalidation" as a whole and this makes perfect sense! If you turn it into an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one make a partial move out of a variable the parent variable cannot be used as a whole anymore, since you have stored the object in a vector this is forbidden, for instance the vector may need to move to reallocate more space.